# everytime my input is numbers with commas like 3,14 or 15.05 it throws an exception but does not write back the statement written in the first else

Tags: java, arrays

As said, my code does not accept non-whole numbers, which is the point of the program, but it throws exception instead of getting to the `else` statement

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Minimum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int zahl1;
        int zahl2;
        int zahl3;
        
        System.out.print("Bitte geben Sie drei Zahlen ! ");
        zahl1 = keyboard.nextInt();
        zahl2 = keyboard.nextInt();
        zahl3 = keyboard.nextInt();
        
        int[] zahlen = new int[] { zahl1, zahl2, zahl3 };
        
        if (zahl1 % 1 == 0 && zahl2 % 1 == 0 && zahl3 % 1 == 0) {   
            int min = getMin(zahlen);
            System.out.println("Minimum ist : "+ min);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Die angegebene Zahl ist ungültig !!");
            // this statement does not show up when I enter a non whole number
        } // end if-else
    } // end main


    private static int getMin(int[] zahlen) {       
            
        int minimum = zahlen[0]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < zahlen.length; i++) { 
            int zahl = zahlen[i];
            
            if (zahl < minimum) { 
                minimum = zahlen[i]; 
            } // end if
        } // end for
            
        return minimum;         
    } // end getMin
}
```

Comment: I recommend reading a tutorial on exceptions, e.g. [this one by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is you are using int which stands for integer = only full numbers such as 1, 5, 7. If you want to use decimals you need float/double.

Answer (score 0):

If a non-integer is expected in the input, related variables need to be declared as `double` and accordingly they are read using `keyboard.nextDouble()`.
After that you may validate if these numbers are integer, and print a message.

Updated code of `main` method may look as follows:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Bitte geben Sie drei Zahlen ! ");

    double zahl1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    double zahl2 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    double zahl3 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    
    if (zahl1 % 1 == 0 && zahl2 % 1 == 0 && zahl3 % 1 == 0) {
        int[] zahlen = {(int) zahl1, (int) zahl2, (int) zahl3};
        int min = getMin(zahlen);
        System.out.println("Minimum ist : "+ min);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Die angegebene Zahl ist ungültig !!");
        // this statement does not show up when I enter a non whole number
    } // end if-else
} // end main
```